# Bundling in asp.net mvc 4.0 does not include all jquery libraries?

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc-4

Overall in my application I get a **jquery ui error** when the dialog stuff is run.
I see in my visual studio solution explorer that the jquery 1.8.2 and modernizer 2.6.2 is loaded in the windows internet explorer.

But why is the rest not included like the jquery ui for the dialog?

Thats the default asp.net mvc 4.0 project code:

```
bundles.Add(new ScriptBundle("~/bundles/jquery").Include(
                        "~/Scripts/jquery-{version}.js"));

            bundles.Add(new ScriptBundle("~/bundles/jqueryui").Include(
                        "~/Scripts/jquery-ui-{version}.js"));

            bundles.Add(new ScriptBundle("~/bundles/jqueryval").Include(
                        "~/Scripts/jquery.unobtrusive*",
                        "~/Scripts/jquery.validate*"));

            // Use the development version of Modernizr to develop with and learn from. Then, when you're
            // ready for production, use the build tool at http://modernizr.com to pick only the tests you need.
            bundles.Add(new ScriptBundle("~/bundles/modernizr").Include(
                        "~/Scripts/modernizr-*"));

            bundles.Add(new StyleBundle("~/Content/css").Include("~/Content/site.css"));

            bundles.Add(new StyleBundle("~/Content/themes/base/css").Include(
                        "~/Content/themes/base/jquery.ui.core.css",
                        "~/Content/themes/base/jquery.ui.resizable.css",
                        "~/Content/themes/base/jquery.ui.selectable.css",
                        "~/Content/themes/base/jquery.ui.accordion.css",
                        "~/Content/themes/base/jquery.ui.autocomplete.css",
                        "~/Content/themes/base/jquery.ui.button.css",
                        "~/Content/themes/base/jquery.ui.dialog.css",
                        "~/Content/themes/base/jquery.ui.slider.css",
                        "~/Content/themes/base/jquery.ui.tabs.css",
                        "~/Content/themes/base/jquery.ui.datepicker.css",
                        "~/Content/themes/base/jquery.ui.progressbar.css",
                        "~/Content/themes/base/jquery.ui.theme.css"));
```

**UPDATE**

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <link href="~/favicon.ico" rel="shortcut icon" type="image/x-icon" />
    <meta charset="utf-8" />
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width" />
    <title>@ViewBag.Title</title>
    @Styles.Render("~/Content/css")
    @Scripts.Render("~/bundles/jquery")
    @Scripts.Render("~/bundles/modernizr")        

    <script type="text/javascript">


    </script>
</head>
<body>
    <div id="logo" />
    <div id="NavigationPanel">     

    </div>
    <div id="ContentPanel">
        @RenderBody()
    </div>   
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Can you post the code for your _layout.cshtml view?

Comment: I did now see my update above.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Just as I suspected, looks like you have not made reference to your jqueryui bundle in the _layout file.  You will need another call to the @Scripts helper:

```
@Scripts.Render("~/bundles/jqueryui")
```

as well as a reference to the jquery ui css files:

```
@Styles.Render("~/Content/themes/base/css")
```